# Pivot - How would i do this?

Tags: sql, pivot

I have following Table:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦═══════╗
║ productid ║ IsProcess ║ IsCosmetic ║ Yield ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬═══════╣
║         1 ║         1 ║          0 ║ 0,99  ║
║         1 ║         0 ║          1 ║ 0,98  ║
║         2 ║         1 ║          0 ║ 0,85  ║
║         2 ║         0 ║          1 ║ 0,9   ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩═══════╝
```

And I need to create this:

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════╗
║ product id ║ Process Yield ║ Cosmetic Yield ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╣
║          1 ║ 0,99          ║ 0,98           ║
║          2 ║ 0,85          ║ 0,9            ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════╝
```

How would I do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select productid,
       sum(IsProcess * Yield) ProcessYield,
       sum(IsCosmetic * Yield) CosmeticYield
from myTable
group by productid
```